# BigQuery - Query for each elements

Tags: sql, foreach, google-bigquery

I would like to loop over several elements for a query.

Here is the query :

```
SELECT
  timestamp_trunc(timestamp, DAY) as Day,
  count(1) as Number
FROM `table`
WHERE user_id="12345" AND timestamp >= '2021-07-05 00:00:00 UTC' AND timestamp <= '2021-07-08 23:59:59 UTC'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY Day
```

So I have for the user "12345" a row counter per each day between two dates, this is perfect.

But I would like to do this query for each user_id of my table.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  timestamp_trunc(timestamp, DAY) as Day,
  user_id,
  count(1) as Number
FROM `table`
WHERE timestamp >= '2021-07-05 00:00:00 UTC' AND timestamp <= '2021-07-08 23:59:59 UTC'
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY Day
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! The problem with this solution is the days are in row, I would like the days in column, so I have only one row per each user. I will update my question. Thank you again

Comment: Changing already answered question is not welcome here on SO! Your original question is answered! if you have new or follow up question - please post it as a new question and I/we will be happy to help!

Comment: Ok totally understand thank you, so I will post a new one and set the original question back :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the users, then use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT timestamp_trunc(timestamp, DAY) as Day,
       COUNTIF(user_id = 12345) as cnt_12345,
       COUNTIF(user_id = 67) as cnt_67,
       COUNTIF(user_id = 89) as cnt_89
FROM `table`
WHERE timestamp >= '2021-07-05 00:00:00 UTC' AND
      timestamp <= '2021-07-09 00:00:00 UTC'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Note the change that I made to the time comparison as well -- so you don't have to worry about fractions of a second before midnight.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I don't know exactly the list of users :(